# Android: Is it possible to do a query on a Cursor?

Tags: android, cursor

Once you have retrieved a set of values with a Cursor, is it possible to do a query on the Cursor itself?

I have retrieved a load of names in alphabetical order and I would like to identify which row ids contain the start of names with different letters. e.g. Rows starting with 'A' start at row id=0, rows starting with 'B' starts at row id=2036, rows starting with 'C' start at row id = 4236 and so on.

Is the only way to do this to iterate through all of the names returned by the Cursor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The structure of the Cursor makes it impossible to be queried. You can assume a Cursor to be something like a list. It does not support SQL like query. So as you have mentioned, looping is one possibility.

Or you can have multiple cursors with different set of queries like row ids contain the start of names with different letters. e.g. Rows starting with 'A' start at row id=0, rows starting with 'B' starts at row id=2036, rows starting with 'C' start at row id = 4236 and so on.

The second method will definitely be more efficient in terms of Time constraint.